# Magento VarienForm validation within Fancybox

Tags: jquery, validation, magento, prototype, fancybox-2

I have a form which validates fine on initial page load, however once it has been loaded within Fancybox it fails to validate and simply submits the form.
I can only assume this is because the VarienForm needs to be reinitiated/restarted, but I cannot figure out how.

The below code loads the form into Fancybox;

**Note:** I am detatching/appending the form on load/close because the clone was duplicating the form causing there to be two elements with the same ID.

```
jQuery.fancybox({
    content:jQuery('#optionsSubmit').clone(true),
    padding:0,
    title:false,
    type:'html',
    afterLoad:function(){
        jQuery('#optionsSubmitContainer #optionsSubmit').detach();
    },
    beforeClose:function(){
        jQuery('#optionsSubmit').appendTo('#optionsSubmitContainer');
    }
});
```

And the below to validate the form;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var optionsSubmit = new VarienForm('optionsSubmit', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try submitting the form via ajax (`POST`) after a success validation instead (I wouldn't clone it though). You have to make sure the whole form is inside fancybox (including the `<form>` tag) so you might need to target the form's container. Then you may need to initialize the VarienForm inside the `afterLoad` fancybox callback